# if __FILE__ == $0 break program when it's placed before any methods

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby and am trying to understand a behavior that I've run into. I'm writing a class that needs some constants initialized before it can run, but when its run from another class, as it sometimes will be, I get warnings about constants already being defined. So I placed the following at the end of my file:

```
if __FILE__ == $0
  constant_initialiation

  ReviewScraper.new.getReviews($testing, $getWeekendReviews, $clearWorksheet, $getAll)
end
```

The `constant_initialization` is just a bunch of constants being set, nothing interesting. Anyway, this works great for me -- so long as its at the end of the file. If I move this up to the top and try running, I get an error: `unitialized constant ReviewScraper (NameError)`. Almost as if it compiles sequentially for just this part of the file and isn't finding the ReviewScraper class definition when its run.

Can any Ruby geniuses explain this behavior to me? It's no big issue other than for styling purposes (I like having my list of constants up top), but it would be nice to understand what's going on here.

Comment: Ruby scripts execute from top to bottom. So, if you call a class or method before it is defined, Ruby has no idea what it is (hence `NameError`). It is like talking to someone about Darth Vader when they have only seen Star Wars Episode 1 and 2.

Comment: Note that my above explanation does not apply to defining methods _inside_ a class. You can define those in any order. That's because Ruby reads the entire class and builds it into a class before it is ever instantiated.

Comment: Ahhh, OK, I think this all makes sense now. I was running into a lot of weird situations as I played around with it and I think they can all be explained withy our explanation. Thank you for clearing that up!

Comment: You could check, if a constant is defined and if not, then create it. Example: `MYCONSTANT = 1 unless defined? MYCONSTANT`

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell: a class body is a Ruby script like any other Ruby script, it gets executed top-to-bottom, left-to-right (ignoring operator precedence), using methods or variables before they are defined will break just as it will with any other script.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I should have clarified. It isn't that the top-to-bottom doesn't apply to defining methods inside a class. What I meant was that inside a class definition, you can define a method called `destroy_planet` that in turn calls a method called `prepare_weapon`. However, `prepare_weapon` can be defined anywhere in the class. It does not have to be defined before `destroy_planet`. That's what I was trying to get across.

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell: it still has to be defined before it is called, though, whether directly or indirectly: `class DeathStar; def destroy_planet; prepare_weapon(); end; new.destroy_planet; def prepare_weapon; end end # -e:1:in 'destroy_planet': undefined method 'prepare_weapon' for #<DeathStar:0x007fa1c1871aa8> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: @JörgWMittag Is it a common practice to instantiate an object from within its own declaration? I'll admit that I have never done that in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I'll expand on my comments above as to what is going on. Secondly, I'll suggest perhaps a better way of setting your constants in code that avoids setting them multiple times.

As I mentioned, a Ruby script reads from top to bottom. So, if you try to instantiate a class *before* you define it, they the Ruby script won't know what it is.

```
cat = Cat.new # NameError

class Cat
   # Code
end

cat = Cat.new # Works fine
```

The script first reads the line where you make a new `Cat` object. However, it doesn't know what a `Cat` is yet. Once it is done processing the code for what a `Cat` is, then it can create one. I used the example of talking to someone about Darth Vader but it is probably more akin to asking a construction company to build your building before you've ever handed them a blueprint. It is only after they have the blueprint that they can build a your building.

Now, in regards to initializing constants, there are a couple different things you could do. One is, you could put the initializations in a if block much like you did at the top but leave out the instantiating of the class until the end of the script. (Two if statements.) Another would be to put the constants in a module in its own file.

```
module Names
    Dog = "Spot"
    Cat = "Sparkles"
end
```

Now you just require that file wherever you need it. In file_one.rb you put

```
require_relative './modules/names_module.rb' # Or wherever it is
include Names
```

You put the same thing in your Review Scraper file. Here's the cool part: if you require the Names module once, it'll be brought into the code. However, if you require it a second time nothing will happen. You won't get warnings. It'll just quietly not require it a second time. One top of that, all your constants are in their own namespace.

Just a thought.

Comment: I like that solution quite a bit, and your explanation is spot on to clear everything up for me. It all just clicked as to why I was getting each and every error I got in the different situations. I'm still fairly new to Ruby but am loving every minute of figuring it out, it's quite the language.